# ng-model on hidden razor input not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC 5 Razor view, I created a hidden field, like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FormData.UserId,
                new { ng_model = "selectedEmployee.userId" })
```

When I perform the necessary angular action to fill the `selectedEmployee.userId` property, the hidden input's value is not filled.

But, when I change it to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FormData.UserId,
                 new { ng_model = "selectedEmployee.userId" })
```

It's working and the data is posted to the server.

And

```
<input type="hidden" name="FormData.UserId" value="{{selectedEmployee.userId}}">
```

is working, but

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FormData.UserId,
              new { value = "{{selectedEmployee.userId}}" })
```

is not. (which probably has to do with Razor overwriting the HTML value)

What's the reason that in Razor a hidden input with an ng-model is not working?

Comment: Whats not working exactly? Is it `value=""` or is value not rendered?

Comment: try to use ng_value="selectedEmployee.userId" instead value

Comment: When I post the hidden value back, it's empty. But when I post it back as a textbox, it has the right value

Comment: Thanks @sylwester, that's the answer. Can you add it below?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please change value into ng_value

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FormData.UserId,
              new { ng_value = "{{selectedEmployee.userId}}" })
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to assign a value to Hidden field. ***'V'*** character of value attribute must be Capital letter.

```
<div data-ng-controller="MyFunction">
    @{Html.BeginForm("SchoolMedium", "BasicSetup", FormMethod.Post, new { });

    @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.SchoolMediumId, new { Value = "{{mascotmedium.SchoolMediumId}}" });


        Html.EndForm();
    }
```

and in controller

```
$scope.EditWhenAdded= function(row){           
 $scope.mascotmedium = row.entity;
};
```

Comment: This worked for me instead of the chosen answer. +1 for simplicity :)

(Just to clarify: the chosen answer gets the ng-value attribute updated, but the value is never posted because attribute "value" is never updated. This answer though, doesn't need anything on controller side)